# How do I get a div to be positioned above an image?

Tags: html, css

Here is what i got:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row_1" >

    <div class="col col-4"> 
    <div class="newstext"> nope nope</div>
     <div class="btn"> a </div>

       <img src="http://dimon12.moy.su/_ph/5/2/242933281.jpg"  width="300" height="350">


    </div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    width:960px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;


}

.row {
    overflow:hidden;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    }

.col {
float:left;
margin:0 10px 0 10px;


    }

.col-4 {
    margin-bottom:20px;
    z-index:-100;

}

.col-12 {
    width:940px;
    height:135px;
   font-family: "proxima-nova"; 
   color:#f1e39b; 
    letter-spacing: .2em;
   font-size:45px;
  padding-top: 50px;

}

.newstext {
    height:50px;
    font-size:10px;
    font-family: "proxima-nova";
    padding-left:10px; padding-top:10px;
    z-index:1;
    background-color:#f1e39b;
    }

.btn{
width:50px;
height:50px;
background-color:#993;
border-radius:25px;
z-index:100;
bottom: 10px;
left: 10px; 
}
```

What i want is to get the .btn to be positioned in the bottom left corner of the picture. So the btn div has to be "above" the picture. I tried this via z-index but that din´t work.

Any ideas?

Here is a fiddle of how i currently looks
http://jsfiddle.net/TVNEV/1/

Comment: you aren't closing those `<div>`s...

Comment: you forgot to close <div>

Comment: they are closed in the original code, thats not the problem

Comment: here with closed divs http://jsfiddle.net/TVNEV/6/

Comment: please use proper language in the forum… :)

Comment: i had to flag a comment. not sure whether it was you or somebody else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see below HTML and css

```
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row_1" >

        <div class="col col-4"> 
        <div class="newstext"> nope nope</div>
<div class="testing">    
     <div class="btn"> a </div>

           <img src="http://dimon12.moy.su/_ph/5/2/242933281.jpg"  width="300" height="350">
    </div>

        </div>
```

CSS

```
.testing {
position:relative;
}
.btn {
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
left:0;
z-index:999;
}
```

Comment: Please correct your style attribute on image like this  style:"z-index:-100;

see now http://jsfiddle.net/TVNEV/14/

let me know if still not working

Comment: Please let me know status of this it's done or still having issue

Answer (score 1):

Add the following in respective classes of your css

```
.col-4 {
 position:relative;
}
.btn {
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/TVNEV/9/)

*Side note: It might be a good idea to read about how it works when you're about to use a new css property… :)*

Comment: @user3744225 can you explain what exactly is not working..? and why a late answer is accepted, which is a duplicate of this answer..?

Answer (score 0):

```
just see this fiddle::http://jsfiddle.net/aashi/TVNEV/5/
```

you have to put the imag in a position relative div and then the button in a position absolute position inside position relative div

Answer (score 0):

you need add `position: absolute;` in you `.btn` class

Answer (score 0):

You should use `position: absolute`. You will need three things:

1. Make sure that the parent of the `.btn` element doesn't have `position: static`, which is the default. If you don't want to move the parent around, usually you can just set it to `position: relative`;
2. Set your div to `position: absolute`;
3. Set the `top`, `left`, `right` or `bottom` properties to place your button. In your case, it would be `bottom: 0` and `left: 0`.

Comment: Ok but the the bottom 0 and left 0 is from the screen ?

Comment: No, it is relative to the first ancestor which is not `position: static`. This is why I recommended setting `position: relative` to the father.

Answer (score 0):

This answer may help you

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row_1" >
        <div class="col col-4"> 
            <div class="newstext"> nope nope</div>
            <div class="imageDiv">
                <div class="btn"> a </div>
                <img src="http://dimon12.moy.su/_ph/5/2/242933281.jpg"  width="300" height="350" />
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width:960px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;


}

.row {
    overflow:hidden;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    }

.col {
float:left;
margin:0 10px 0 10px;


    }

.col-4 {
    margin-bottom:20px;
    z-index:-100;

}

.col-12 {
    width:940px;
    height:135px;
   font-family: "proxima-nova"; 
   color:#f1e39b; 
    letter-spacing: .2em;
   font-size:45px;
  padding-top: 50px;

}

.newstext {
    height:50px;
    font-size:10px;
    font-family: "proxima-nova";
    padding-left:10px; padding-top:10px;
    z-index:1;
    background-color:#f1e39b;
    }

.btn{
width:50px;
height:50px;
background-color:#993;
border-radius:25px;
z-index:100;
bottom: 10px;
left: 10px; 
}

.imageDiv{position:relative;}
.imageDiv .btn{position:absolute;bottom:0;left:0;}
```

**Working Example**

http://jsfiddle.net/Rn3fF/

Answer (score 0):

I would just use the image as a div background

```
#the_div {
 background-image: url('your_image.gif');
}


<div id="the_div">
  <div id ="the button"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: i can´t the image is the content of the page an changes for every .col-4.

Comment: you could set an inline style for this but it is not a neat solution, so absolute positioning is a better solution :)